# How to remove filename from a path with only JS?

Tags: javascript, regex, path, filenames

i was looking everywhere to a way of remove only the filename of a path with JS, but I only find information of how to remove the path, and keep the filename.
I have this path:

> C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\CyT\Proyectos\AlmPas\2022-06-17\luis@gmail.com\1234567890.zip

But then, i only need the path:

> C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\CyT\Proyectos\AlmPas\2022-06-17\luis@gmail.com\

If i use the next code, i get the filename only, but how can i get the path without the filename?

```
soloArchivo = ruta_archivos.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract with this regular expression:

```js
const str = String.raw`C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\CyT\Proyectos\AlmPas\2022-06-17\luis@gmail.com\1234567890.zip`
const regex = /^.*[\\\/]/;
const match = str.match(regex);
if (match) {
    console.log(match[0])
} else {
    console.log("Sorry, there is no match.")
}
```

**Results**: `C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\CyT\Proyectos\AlmPas\2022-06-17\luis@gmail.com\`

**PATTERN EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\/]                     any character of: '\/'
```

Comment: If i run the snipet in here, will work perfectly, but I put it on VSCode and gets 2 error, when i run get this in console : SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' and in the end of the line before the .[0]) gets 1) an expression was expected and then 2) 
Was expected ":"

Comment: @LuizVillalba Code downgraded.